# Vuex Shared Actions

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I noticed that many of my vuex actions reused certain methods like this block inside of `SomeFeatureActions.ts`

```
export const actions: ActionTree<AutomationState, any> = {
    require({ state, dispatch }, type) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to create a base class that implements `ActionTree<S, R>` with `require` provided to all implementations of this base class.

I tried to use something like this

```
export class StoreAction<S, R> implements ActionTree<S, R> {
    public require({ state, dispatch }, type) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Which doesn't work.. What am I missing?